# How should email addresses be pasted from a text file into a to/cc/bcc?

Tags: gmail, opera

Asking on behalf of a friend.

OS: Win XP SP3
Browser: Opera

He maintain separate lists of email addresses on the computer in a plain text file. Depending upon the content, he pastes specific list/s into the TO/CC/BCC field.

Over the past week, or thereabouts -July 2022- gmail will not paste addresses into the to/cc/bcc field. Until that date, everything was peachy. Now, only the first email address from the clipboard is reproduced in the chosen to/cc/bcc field. All other addresses - still in the clipboard - are discarded by gmail.

How should all email addresses in the clipboard be pasted into the relevant to/cc/bcc field of the email?

Comment: This doesn't look to be Gmail problem. Try using Opera in private / safe mode with all the extensions disabled and using a supported web-browser -> https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6557?hl=en

Comment: are there commas or semicolons after each line in the text file?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: The email lists are comma separated with the name of the contact escaped by angular brackets. There wasn't an issue until a few days ago.